# Steam authentication with Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, passport.js, steam-web-api

I'm trying to do authentication with Steam from the home page in Angular but whenever I click on button (which has `(click)` event pointing at `login()` function in `AppComponent`), instead of being redirected to Steam page, current page is refreshed and nothing happens.

This is server-side code:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
const jwt = require('express-jwt');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const SteamStrategy = require('passport-steam').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(cors());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database_test');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => {
    done(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new SteamStrategy({
        returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/steam/return',
        realm: 'http://localhost:3000',
        apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }, 
    (identifier, profile, done) => {
        process.nextTick(() => {
            profile.identifier = identifier;
            return done(null, profile);
        });
    }
));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/auth/steam',
    passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:4200/home' }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.json({"success": true, "res": res});
    }
);

app.get('/auth/steam/return', 
    passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:4200/home' }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.json({"success": true, "res": res});
    }
);

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Backend listening on port 3000.');
});
```

This is `AuthenticationService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { JwtHelper, tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  domain = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  login() {
    return this.http.get(this.domain + '/auth/steam').map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

This is `AppComponent`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ AuthenticationService ]
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

  login(): void {
    this.authService.login().subscribe(data => {
      alert(data);
    });
  }

}
```

Both servers are running (Angular and Node).

**Edit:** I added button instead of link and log showed me there is an error with [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Just wanted to add, kudos for doing stuff with Steam. I'm mostly droning with business/corporate stuff with Angular, and judging by StackOverflow traffic, most others are. You're distinctive in doing something which is, I assume, gaming-related! Good luck to you, sir, and have all the fun, and then have some more fun for the rest of us :)

Answer (score 8):

Simply said, you can't redirect your Angular service to your backend=>steam=>backend callback url. You have to redirect the user there.

So instead of calling the `authService.login()`, just add a direct link, like said elsewhere. I don't see the first link in your backend code, but frontend code suggests `/auth/steam` like in SteamStrategy docs.

So, step 1 is this:

```
// change the login() method on AuthService
login() {
  window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/auth/steam";
}
```

(You'll want to take that URL from `environment` or some such later on.)

What happens now:

1. Browser goes to `localhost:3000/auth/steam`
2. Node redirects the browser to steam openId
3. Steam, on successfull login and auth grant, redirects back to `http://localhost:3000/auth/steam/return`

What happens next?

- Well, first, save that profile data in Passport strategy to user's profile, or at least to user's session.
- then, *redirect the user back to Angular app*. Something like this:

  `res.redirect('/public/#/authcallback`)`

(Using HashLocationStrategy here so you see clearly where I was redirecting you.)

- Now, your `/authcallback` route in Angular should probably hit the endpoint directly once more, to get the auth data, before doing it's own redirects.

Alternatives:

Now, that last part could be done differently. You *could* do something like redirect from node back to index or to whatever the original route was (you could add those as params etc). Then, have an Angular service, that *always* checks back with backend if there is auth data.

Or you could have your node backend *embed* the info in Angular's `index.html` or whatever page you're using. You know, old-school, server-side inject data in maybe a script tag with something like `ejs` or `jade`. It would be faster, but I'd still not trust it blindly on client (or server) and would double-check, maybe in background.

Comment: Answer helped me as well. Well written, thanks Zlatko.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in your code calls a GET request to your own server. I dont see any page redirection at all.

If you want to redirect the user to *an external website* you need to send the user there, either :

From HTML file :

```
<a href="http://example.com">Link to steam</a>
```

From your component .ts file:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'
```

If you want to redirect the user to *another page on your website*, you need to use the Angular Router :

From HTML file :

```
<a routerLink="/component-one">Component One</a>
```

From your component .ts file :

```
this.router.navigate(['/component-one']);
```

So you component now becomes :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ AuthenticationService ] // This should be provided by the module, not the component
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

  login(): void {
    this.authService.login().subscribe(data => {
      alert(data);
      this.router.navigate('/to-some-page');
    });
  }

}
```

More examples can be found with a simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular2%20router%20example), like the one below
https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-routing

Comment: Redirection is done through Passport's ```authenticate``` method automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are never directing the user to a steam page. Your comment to klong: "Redirection is done through Passport's". This might be, however you are never sending you user to a specific page. You are simply making a GET request form you frontend.

About the Same-origin policy error. I assume this is caused by Passport because you use Cors on your express server. I think the best solution would be to create a simple proxy. If you use the CLI you can use [this example](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not send your login request to express backend. You must send your login request to steam oidc authorize endpoint. See what Steam says:

> When using OpenID, the user begins in a web browser at the third-party website. When the user wishes to login/link their account to that website, using OpenID, the site directs the user to a login form on the Steam Community website. Once the user has entered their Steam login credentials, the user's web browser is automatically redirected back to the 3rd party website with some additional OpenID specific data appended to the return URL. The site's OpenID library can then use this data to verify and obtain the user's SteamID.

It is called Oidc and lucky you there's two good libraries for Angular. [This (Recommended)](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/) and [This](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/).

What your express server need to do is validate the token recieved from your angular client before request. I'm not very familiar with express but, I'm sure there is at least a couple of libraries for you to validate token.

Also you need to do more research on this topic.